# SQL: Adding up quantities for certain dates on per File Number

Tags: mysql, sql, database, printing

I am very new to SQL / MYSQL I have only done some reading and some stuff on code academy, so I apologize if this is a newby mistake.

I have an SQL server hooked up to our printers that list out jobs, Quantity, and the dates of each job sent to the printer.

I was wondering is there a way for me to set it up so when all this data is exported to a .cvs file it automatically adds up the quantities on each date that match and each job number that match?

I understand I can do it in excel after the fact (this is what I have been doing) but it just feels tedious and time-consuming.

Below is how we have it set up to export to the .cvs file.

```
Field Mapping 1           : DB 'cc_name' , Exp 'Client' 
Field Mapping 2           : DB 'su_IdentityType_LDAPLogin' , Exp 'User' 
Field Mapping 3           : DB 'FIXVALUE' , Exp 'Description' 
Field Mapping 4           : DB 'su_date' , Exp 'Date' 
Field Mapping 5           : DB 'su_cardinality' , Exp 'Quantity' 
Field Mapping 6           : DB 'su_rate' , Exp 'Price' 
Field Mapping 7           : DB 'su_amountpaid' , Exp 'Total'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes:

```
    select

    p.printdate,
    SUM(p.quantity)

    from printers p

    group by p.printdate
```